# problem in batch script read user input

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, user-input

i use `set /p` below to read user input
it seems to work outside the if block but the one inside if block doesn't work.
When i run the script second time the user input in the if block prints the previous user input.

test script:

```
@echo off
set cond=true
echo %cond%
if %cond%==true (
echo "cond is true"
REM the below input doesn't work
set /p name1="enter your name"
echo name is: %name1%
)

REM it works here
set /p name2="enter your name"
echo name is: %name2%
```

thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read up on delayed expansion in `help set`.

By default environment variables (`%foo%`) are expanded when `cmd` parses a line. And a line in this case is a single statement which can include a complete parenthesized block. So after parsing of a block all occurrences of environment variables are replaced with its value *at the time of parsing*. If you change a variable in the block and use it after that again, you will see the old value, simply because it has already been replaced.

Delayed expansion, which can be enabled with

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

causes environment variables marked up with exclamation marks instead of percent signs (`!foo!`) to be evaluated directly before *executing* a statement which is *after* parsing.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion enableextensions
set cond=true
echo %cond%
if %cond%==true (
echo "cond is true"
REM the below input does work now
set /p name1="enter your name"
echo name is: !name1!
)
```

Comment: You can also start `CMD.EXE` using the `/V:ON` switch.

Comment: @neal: For most batch files that's not a viable option.

Comment: thank you very much...this is new to me ..do you know suggest any good resource where i can read about it?

Comment: one more question this must work on all flavours of windows right? xp,vista,win7,etc

Comment: Works since NT 4. And there are several batch file resources out there; http://robvanderwoude.com/ and http://ss64.com/ spring to mind. However I usually just need the built-in documentation and learned most of what I know by experimenting and solving problems.